# get_user_by in external scripts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a PHP script which requires wp-load.php at the beginning. For some reason, I don't get any user data when using get_user_by, however, when using the same 3 lines inside a regular WordPress page, I get the correct results.

The code in the external PHP script:

```
require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");
$current_user = get_user_by('login','Cloud user 1');
print_r($current_user);
```

If I use the last 2 lines from the above in a regular WordPress page, I get results.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, silly me. I inserted one too many '..' in the wp-load.php line which caused to load the wrong wp-load and wrong WordPress installation (the one in my main domain instead of the one in the subdomain).